# Subscribing a Gitter Chat / IRC channel to receive Notifications of all new questions of a Tag on Stack Overflow

Tags: gratis, linux, chat, rss, stack-exchange

Our tool often gets questions on stack overflow.
They all use its tag.

I've seen on Stack Exchange chat, that it can be set up so that questions are automatically reposted from the site, to the chat room.

Shown below for Software Rec stack-exchange, getting questions reposted from it's Meta.

[image: Chat example]

I am looking for a tool I can use to mimic this on **[gitter](http://gitter.im) or IRC**.
Our IRC and gitter already automatically repost to each other via an existing bot, so sending the notification to one would send to the other.

**Alternatively, sending the notifications to the Gitter activity bar** would be good. Better even.

Since we have a moderately active group of people on IRC/gitter willing to answer questions, it would be good to gather the questions in one place.

I guess a RSS subscriber bot might do it.

I am willing to host a 3rd party bot to do it, on my server.
**Such a bot must run on linux.**

#### Summary:

- Detect new uses of tag on Stackoverflow
- Post them on one or more of:

  - Gitter Chat
  - Gitter Activity Bar
  - IRC chanel
- Run on Linux
- Free, and ideally opensource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [StackOverflowGitterNotifier.jl](https://github.com/oxinabox/StackOverflowGitterNotifier.jl/)

Here you go, I made this specially for you.

It posts in to the activity side bar on gitter.
Note that depending on how you are syncing IRC and gitter this may mean it does not show up on IRC.
For the default IRC interface to gitter all action on the activity sidebar is posted as an IRC message.
Since you say you are using a Bot. I don't know how it will interact, it might not repost them depending on the bot's setup.

Stackoverflow question feeds have a nice clean RSS based feed of questions.
Gitter Custom notification integration exposes a url you can just hit with a HTTP PUSH action to make something show up. (to get that URL you will need to be a channel admin)

Throwing these 70 lines together only took about 1.5 hours, including discovering and learning those API's.

It is programmed in [Julia](http://julialang.org), and expected v0.4+ It will throw deprecation warnings in 0.4, but if you go to 0.5 it should stop doing that.

I've tested this only on linux, but it should run on anything that [Julia](http://julialang.org) supports. (So also Windows and Mac).

You need to run it every 5 minutes or so, using CRON etc.

It is under the MIT license.

[image: Demo]